# BJT circuit of 2 transistors

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt

For VB2 = 7.5V and VB1 = 2.5V we get:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDtgfR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assume Q1 operates in the linear region(forward active) , Q2 operates in the linear region

IE1 = VB1-VBE/R1 = 1.9/100 = 19mA

IC1 = β/β+1IE1 = 18mA

VR2 = IC1*R2 = 1.8V

VE2 = VB2-0.6 = 6.9V VC1E1 = VE2-VR2-VE1 = 6.9-1.8-1.9 = 3.2V>VCEsat(Q1)->Q1 is operating in the linear region(forward active).

Holding VB1 costant(2.5V)which is the lowest voltage VB2 before Q1 enters saturation?And which is the lowest voltage VB2 before Q2 stops conducting current?

Comment: For a 0th order approximation, \$V_{\text{B}_2} >= V_{\text{CE}_1}+(V_{\text{B}_1}-V_\text{BE})\frac{R_2}{R_1}+V_\text{BE}\$ and \$V_{\text{B}_1}\ge V_\text{BE}\$.

Comment: @jonk why is that?

Comment: \$Q_1\$ is an emitter follower generating a current in \$R_1\$ and this current must flow through \$R_2\$. But I may be misunderstanding your writing, too. Can't say for sure.

Comment: @jonk I will edit so it is better understandable.

Comment: You are asking if you are correct but you are not asking about analyzing the circuit. You are wrong but if you would analyze the circuit you'd see where, on your own. How is it that you are able to assert, with positiveness, that \$Q_1\$ is saturated for the purposes of your claim (1), ignoring \$R_2\$, and also at the same time fail to notice the requirement that \$Q_2\$'s base-emitter junction must also be active? There's so much I don't follow in terms of how you are thinking. So I'm not at all sure how I may help.

Comment: But Q2 is active.I am just saying that if VC1<VB1 or IC1*R2>VE2-VE1-VCEsat(Q1) the Q1 is saturated and if VB2<=VC1 then Q2 will be in cutoff

Comment: That's a claim, by fiat. Nothing more. (I can also make random claims, too. Not that any of them would mean something.) I'd like to first see your analysis that demonstrates the conditions under which that is true. In fact, I kind of imagined that was what you were asking about earlier. Don't make claims. Show me. Prove to me what you claim is true and under what conditions it is so. I may be of some use then.

Comment: Ok I will add my analysis.

Comment: I'm still confused. You talk about Q1 being "linear" (which is a term used for MOSFETs, moreso.) But I interpret that as "forward active." But who knows, perhaps you don't mean "forward active" and you mean something different. Also, you discuss the CE saturation of Q1. Why? What, in your mind, ***causes*** that saturation to occur? Do you just "guess" and say that this is a minimum that you can just decide is a minimum? But then what did you mean by "linear"? I could sit down and analyze it for you. But I'm trying to get you to walk through the exact details and understand your terms, too.